# SpamExperts filtering outbound mail

Tags: spam, spam-filter

I've got a hosted domain & mail server. It is attached—somehow—to a SpamExperts installation. I've been training the filter for years and it does a fine job filtering out the incoming garbage.

But recently it has begin to filter my outgoing mail. I might on occasion need to send a simple message:

```
Subject: Requesting a call re UX
Body: What's up with the map filters? I happen to like Pete's Coffee! Call me
```

You get the drift. I can understand how this stuff looks like spam, and the recipient might actually not want to see it either (she's a Starbucks girl) but in the end it needs to go through, and I'm baffled as to how to convince the [Spam Experts](https://www.spamexperts.com/) instance that I'm legit.

Comment: Change your hoster ?

Comment: ...or talk to them.

Comment: In process. In the meantime I have a serverfault discussion going as a second option.